# Why Partial view's fields are null, when I Post the data in Action?

Tags: ios, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My question is about asp.net-MVC:

my problem is: when I click on Submit button in Index View, Address Fields from my Partial view is null...this is my code:

I have a Person Class :

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        Address = new Address();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

and Address class :

```
public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

I was Created an Index view such this. In my view there is a partial view :

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
    <label>Name: </label>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)

    <label>Family</label>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Family)

    @Html.Partial("GetAddress", Model.Address)

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" title="Submit" />
}
```

and my partial view is :

```html
<label>City :</label>
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.City)
<br />
<label>Street: </label>
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Street)
```

this is Image of  Error :
http://8pic.ir/images/eog6owv9h9bbi156tp0r.png

Comment: Does your POST Method accepts `Person`?

Comment: yes.  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Person person)
        {
            ctx.People.Add(person);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding HtmlFieldPrefix when you are calling your partial.

```
 @Html.Partial("GetAddress", Model.Address, new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Address" } })
```

This way you will name your fileds properly and model binder will bind them correctly.

Comment: The property is named `Address` so it needs to `HtmlFieldPrefix = "Address"`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, i think that when `Address` is passed as model to the Partial, the names would be `Address.City` and `Address.Street`, but the model binder expects `Person.Address.City` and `Person.Address.Street`.

Comment: No, that's not correct. The class is typeof `Person` and `Person` contains a property named `Address` so it needs to be `Address.Street` and `Address.City`. If it was `Person.Address.City` it would only bind to a model that contains a property named `Person` which has a property named `Address` which was a complex object and contained a property named `City` (have a look at the html generated by one of your views to understand)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, thank you for that explanation. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: Thanks.My Dear friends. My problem was solved with your help .:)